# Reduce data fetched/displayed from timestamp

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store and fetch the date of a user request.

I'm creating the timestamp like this:

```
const date = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

The way I'm fetching/displaying the data:

```
<tr class="tr-content" *ngFor="let request of requests" routerLink="/admin/requests/{{ request.id }}">
  <th scope="row" class="text-center"> {{ request.id }} </th>
  <td>{{ request.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ request.company }}</td>
  <td>{{ request.type }}</td>
  <td>{{ request.budget }}</td>
  <td>{{ request.date.toDate() }}</td>
  <td class="text-center"> > </td>
</tr>
```

It works, but the data is being displayed like this:

> Sun Jun 30 2019 14:03:37 GMT+0300 (Osteuropäische Sommerzeit)

**How can I reduce the information being displayed?** F.e. to only the date and maybe the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date pipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe and passe a pattern format to it, You can do something like: `<td>{{ request.date.toDate() | date:'dd/MM/yy'}}</td>`.

Or, you can use Moment.JS for this, it works with angular too. see https://github.com/urish/angular-moment.
`

Comment: Glad to help you